# JMS is listener is down for 2 hour then How recover message once it is up from topic

Tags: java, jms, listener

suppose I have Durable Topic and three client as Receiver clientA, clientB, clientC and so on. clientA is down for 2 hour, once clientA is up, how should we have guaranty that clientA will receive all messages from last two hour(which was missed in downtime).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no "Durable Topic". There is "Durable Subscription" which is what you meant I guess. A durable subscription ensures that publications are held by the messaging provider till the consumer (client A in your case) comes back and resumes subscription. Once the consumer resumes subscription, all those publications held by the messaging provider will be delivered.

Comment: agree with you, Client A is down and Client B, C consuming message although topic will store message (which was consumed by B,C) for A Client, I mean once Client A will up then it will get all message.

Comment: If all clients have created their own durable subscription, then A will get all messages when it comes back. If all clients share the same subscription, then A will not get any message.